# MS SQL foreign key select validation on other column

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

i have the following tables

**Categories**
ID (int),
Name (varchar(50)),
Description (varchar(250)),
IsMarket (bit)

**SubCategories**
HeadID (int),
SubID (int)

I've configured both SubCategories.HeadID & SubCategories.SubID to look towards Categories.ID through foreigns keys.

My question is this: Is it possible to make sure i cannot select any Categories.ID at SubCategories.SubID where the Categories.IsMarket value equals true?

Comment: I don't think you can programatically - what would happen if a valid (i.e. IsMarket=0) category got that IsMarket value updated to 1?  Would you want to delete the rows in the child table?

Comment: I did not even consider that action (from a user). Thank you for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0):

The query will be like :

SELECT  T2.HeadId ,
        T2.SubId
FROM    Temp2 T2
        INNER JOIN Temp1 T1H ON T1H.Id = T2.HeadId
        INNER JOIN Temp1 T1S ON T1S.Id = T2.SubId
WHERE   T1S.IsMarket = 1
        AND T1H.IsMarket = 1

Please run the below query with example which have table creation, population and then output:

CREATE TABLE Temp1
    (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      IsMarket BIT
    )

CREATE TABLE Temp2 ( HeadId INT, SubId INT )

INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 0 )
 -- Run 9 Times
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO Temp1
        ( IsMarket )
VALUES  ( 1 )

INSERT  INTO Temp2
        ( HeadId, SubId )
VALUES  ( 1, 2 )
INSERT  INTO Temp2
        ( HeadId, SubId )
VALUES  ( 1, 10 )
INSERT  INTO Temp2
        ( HeadId, SubId )
VALUES  ( 15, 2 )
INSERT  INTO Temp2
        ( HeadId, SubId )
VALUES  ( 10, 1 )

INSERT  INTO Temp2
        ( HeadId, SubId )
VALUES  ( 10, 15 )

SELECT  T2.HeadId ,
        T2.SubId
FROM    Temp2 T2
        INNER JOIN Temp1 T1H ON T1H.Id = T2.HeadId
        INNER JOIN Temp1 T1S ON T1S.Id = T2.SubId
WHERE   T1S.IsMarket = 1
        AND T1H.IsMarket = 1